# Method overloading and polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, overloading

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> myList = new List<A> {new A(), new B(), new C()};

            foreach (var a in myList)
            {
                Render(a);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Render(A o)
        {
            Console.Write("A");
        }

        private static void Render(B b)
        {
            Console.Write("B");
        }

        private static void Render(C c)
        {
            Console.Write("C");
        }
    }

    class A
    {

    }

    class B : A
    {

    }

    class C : A
    {

    }
```

The output is: AAA

Is it possible to somehow use method overloading, so that the output would be: ABC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use dynamic typing if you're using C# 4:

```
foreach (dynamic a in myList)
{
    Render(a);
}
```

Within static typing, overload resolution is performed at compile-time, not at execution time.

For the implementation to be chosen at decision time, you either have to use *overriding* instead of *overloading*, or use dynamic typing as above.

Comment: Even though overload resolution is done at compile time why is it "A a" is chosen over "B b" and "C c".

Comment: @Sandeep: Because the compile-time type of the `a` variable in `Main` is only A, because the list is a `List<A>`. So `Render(a)` can *only* pick `Render(A a)`.

Answer (score 14):

The following ought to do the trick, where we control the behaviour when working with a type within that type:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Render()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

class C : A
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myList = new List<A> { new A(), new B(), new C() };
    foreach (var a in myList)
    {
        a.Render();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And if you want the defined behaviour of a type to be additive to that of its parent, then call the method implemented in the base after executing your own logic, for example:

```
class B : A
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
        base.Render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to accomplish this is with the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern): it allows you to achieve something *like* polymorphism using a two-way method calling system:

```
interface IRenderable
{
    AcceptForRender(Program renderer);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var myList = new List<IRenderable> {new A(), new B(), new C()};

        foreach (var a in myList)
        {
            a.AcceptForRender(p);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void Render(A o)
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }

    public void Render(B b)
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }

    public void Render(C c)
    {
        Console.Write("C");
    }
}

class A : IRenderable
{
    public void AcceptForRender(Program renderer)
    {
        renderer.Render(this);
    }
}

class B : IRenderable
{
    public void AcceptForRender(Program renderer)
    {
        renderer.Render(this);
    }
}

class C : IRenderable
{
    public void AcceptForRender(Program renderer)
    {
        renderer.Render(this);
    }
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it allows you to effectively achieve polymorphism (each type ensures the correct overload is called by passing the strongly-typed `this` to `Render` internally) while keeping logic that does not belong in your types themselves (e.g., visual rendering logic) out.

Answer (score 2):

Make A B C deriving from a base ( abstract ) class, define in that class a method Render and override properly in each A B C . Instead of calling `Render(a)` then call `a.Render()` this is the way polymorfism is supposed to work.